# Get the data from the table in the form of fieldname and fieldvalue in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server

Is it possible to get the data and column name as a key-value pattern like the table `tblemplyee` shown below?

[image]

[image]

Comment: It is definitely possible.  Other than that, please keep in mind that example data is better shown inline than using screenshots.

Comment: If possible can you please tell how can I achieve it?

Comment: The values shown for JoinDate in the desired output look really weird. Is that *really* the format you want?

Comment: sorry. my mistake. no the format should be the same as in table tblemployee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

UNPIVOT can help you with this.

Try something like

```
SELECT employeenumber, fieldname,  fieldvalue
FROM tblmployee e
UNPIVOT(
    FieldValue
    FOR FieldName IN (Gender, JoinDate, MobileNo)
) U
```

Hope that helps

Comment: getting error as "The type of column "MobileNo" conflicts with the type of other columns specified in the UNPIVOT list."

Comment: Convert all the data to a character based datatype before unpivoting

Comment: In your source table Gender, JoinDate etc are each held in a different table and can be given separate data types. When you UNPIVOT these all end up in the same column and must have the same datatype. Which will the DBMS assign? Chances are it will use the first value it processes in whatever execution plan it produces. This runs the risk of implicit conversion failing for some subsequent value. You can avoid this by explicitly converting all source values to the same type, and VARCHAR is one that will work for all possible sources.